# Cantilever support

Tags: load

Using two 2x12 that are 12' long tied to a supporting a Load Bearing ceiling with no floor above, can 24 inches be used as a cantilever to support another load bearing ceiling supporting wall?

To clarify in attached picture, I want to eliminate 24inches as shown or scribbled out, and tie the two 2x12 into that 'B' Support wall. The 'B' wall which is shown in the picture is a wall with an opening cutout. The B 'Portion shown is 15inches wide (*ceiling to end*) from the cutout it is 6' to the tie-in to 'A' Wall.

To simplify my question I would be leaving the B portion and upper A portion and 24" would be removed from the 'A' wall.

Simply having 24 inches now hanging with two 2"x 12" married together  to support the other load bearing wall.

[image]

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are trying to do. The picture does not clarify.  12" 2x12?  ( " is inch )  24" now hanging?  Perhaps you can take minute to think of a different way to explain your are talking about, what is your goal?

Comment: IIUC, you want to cut wall A at the line near A, leaving a 24" long, 12" tall beam that will meet up with the beam labeled B. This means that the current beam B will no longer have wall A to support it, so your cantilever will not only be supporting its own 24", but however long beam B is as well. _Can_ you do this? Sure. Can you do this based on advice from well meaning strangers on the internet? Probably not safely. You _really_ need to have a structural engineer on site to analyze the loads and design the structure or you risk damage and injury or death.

Comment: The end of A may be a post to support a beam in the upper B. We do not know. "*Simply having 24 inches now hanging with two 2x12 married together*".  I still do not understand what that means.

Comment: It's not particularly clear, @AlaskaMan, but I think he wants to have B meet up with a cantilevered beam from wall A without any support underneath, opening up wall A to the front door. I'm sure it's possible with the proper amounts of steel and posts in the right places, but I doubt anybody here would be willing to stick their neck out to say _how_ to go about doing it. Far too many unknowns from this side of the monitor. Even Lee Sam probably wouldn't touch this one with all his engineering knowledge.

Comment: The "'B' wall which is shown in the picture" is most definitely *not* "a wall with an opening cutout". 'B' upper is a beam, 'B' lower is a pony wall or knee wall, and they are entirely separate from each other... Your idea is likely to fail spectacularly unless you completely re-engineer & rebuild both 'A' and 'B'.